# How to copy column to the first blank cell of another column?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

**I have some values in column A that I want to copy  the first empty cell of column B**.

I managed to get the first part of the problem:

```
function CopyValues() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();
  var source = ss.getRange ("MySheet!A4:A10");

  source.copyTo (ss.getRange ("MySheet!B32"), {contentsOnly: true});

}
```

where B32 is the first empty cell in column B.

This works perfectly but of course B32 will not always be first empty cell and i need to get that first empty cell dynamically. I tried a few things by merging other scripts found online, but no success so far...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a function that will return the first empty cell (as a string eg. 'B32') in a given column and sheet:

```
function getFirstEmptyCellInCol(sheet, column) {
  var values = sheet.getRange(column + ':' + column).getValues(); // get all the data of the column
  var rowCount = 0;
  while ( values[rowCount] && values[rowCount][0] != "" ) {
    rowCount++;
  }
  return column + parseInt(rowCount+1).toString();
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("MySheet");
emptyCell = getFirstEmptyCellInCol(sheet,'B');
```

With your code:

```
function CopyValues() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("MySheet");
  var emptyCell = getFirstEmptyCellInCol(sheet,'B');
  var source = sheet.getRange ("A4:A10");
  source.copyTo (sheet.getRange(emptyCell), {contentsOnly: true});
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked perfectly :) 
Have a great day!

Comment: @Kev please consider marking my answer as accepted (check mark on the left) if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function getColumnHeight(col,sh,ss){
  var ss=ss || SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=sh || ss.getActiveSheet();
  var col=col || sh.getActiveCell().getColumn();
  var rg=sh.getRange(1,col,sh.getLastRow(),1);
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  while(vA[vA.length-1][0].length==0){
    vA.splice(vA.length-1,1);
  }
  return vA.length;
}
```

getColumnHeight() + 1 is what you want.

Another version:

```
function getColumnHeight(col,sh,ss){
  var ss=ss||SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=sh||ss.getActiveSheet();
  var col=col||sh.getActiveCell().getColumn();
  const rcA=sh.getRange(1,col,sh.getLastRow(),1).getValues().reverse()
  let s=0;
  for(let i=0;i<rcA.length;i++) {
    if(rcA[i][0].toString().length==0) {
      s++;
    }else{
      break;
    }
  }
  return rcA.length-s;
}
```