# Copy -Paste into next available row in selected column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to write a script that is tied to a button so that when clicked it copies my selected range into the next available row based on contents in column A. I have formulas in column D and currently when ran it pastes into the next available row but I would like it to paste into the next available row based on if column A has data.

Here is what I have so far

```
function myFunction() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();
 var source = ss.getRange ("JOB BUILD!A3:E21");
 var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("JOB IN PROGRESS");
 var destRange = destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow()+1,1);
 source.copyTo (destRange, {contentsOnly: false}) 
      }
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Is there any  problem with your code? What is the question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determining the last row in a single column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17632165/determining-the-last-row-in-a-single-column)

Comment: is this all of your code? I don't see a doGet or any other trigger function. Also, where is this button you mentioned?

Comment: The code works but pastes in the next available row. I would like it to paste in the next available row based on column A and overwrite anything below it. So if column A has data down to row 4 but column D has data down to row 8 id like it to paste in row 5 not row 9

Comment: The button is a drawing that I assigned this script to in google sheets. The code is currently working on the click of the button. I just cannot figure out how to make it paste into the proper range.

Comment: I believe Tanaike has and answer about loading images into a spreadsheet that are used for buttons but I don't remember which one so I'd recommend searching on his answers if you can.  Personally, I would rather build the buttons in the sidebar with html

Comment: [getColumnHeight()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55344474/7215091)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to paste the values based on the last available row from a certain column, you will have to find the last row of that column.

In order to get the last row of a certain row, you can use this method from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17637159). Assuming you want to paste the values based on column `A` from the `destSheet`, you can try the below code:

```
function myFunction() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("JOB BUILD");
    var sourceData = sourceSheet.getRange("A3:E21");
    var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("JOB IN PROGRESS");
    var aRange = destSheet.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
    var colA = aRange.filter(String).length;
    var destRange = destSheet.getRange(colA, "COL_NO", "NO_OF_ROWS", "NO_OF_COLS");
    sourceData.copyTo(destRange, {
        contentsOnly: false
    })
}
```

#### Note

Please bear in mind that depending on the exact structure of your data from the two sheets, you *will* have to adjust the ranges.

#### Reference

- [Determining the last row in a single column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17632165/determining-the-last-row-in-a-single-column);
- [Apps Script Sheet Class - getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns).